# How do i prevent formik yup ( regex ) validation from disappearing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

This is my regex

```
        const firstNameSpecialChars = /[^\/\\#+()$~%.":;*<>{}@]/;
```

This is my validation

```
     const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email(ENTER_VALID_EMAIL_MESSAGE)
      .required(EMAIL_IS_REQUIRED_MESSAGE),
    firstname: Yup.string()
      .trim()
      .matches(
        firstNameSpecialChars,
        'These characters are not allowed in name fields',
      ),
```

I want an error to be shown when there is a regex match.
This works, but there is a problem...
As soon as i type after the hash symbol the error disappears
but when there is a symbol the error shows up

[image]

This is how my error looks like when I type regex chars

[image]

which is not what i want
if there is special char i want the error to be there till the user removes the special char

---

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :

I had to do this :

```
Regex

/^[^#+()$~%.":;*<>{}@\\/\\]+$/
```

This gives me the error when anyone of the stuff inside the [ ] matches

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).